# Compiling a dynamic link library on Ubuntu and getting unrecognised debug output level

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

I am trying to compile a DLL (.so) file on Ubuntu using GCC. The library has one dependency which is a static library which I was able to compile with GCC. I am using the following command line and producing the following error:

```
gcc -shared -Bstatic -gpclib.a -fPIC gpcdll.h gpcdll.c
```

Output:

> cc1: error: unrecognised debug output level ‘pclib.a’
>
> cc1: error: unrecognised debug output level ‘pclib.a’

I have tried googling this error with no success.

Update:

I have attempted running and the following based on recommendation:

```
gcc -shared -Bstatic -lgpclib.a -fPIC gpcdll.h gpcdll.c
```

Result:

> gpcdll.c:19:17: fatal error: gpc.h: No such file or directory
>    #include "gpc.h"
>                    ^
>   This make sense to me because my static library is called gpclib.a and not lgpclib.a

Update #3: I attempted to run with -g to get more debugging information but got nothing more than what was produced prior.

Update #4: gcc -shared -lgpc -gpclib.a -fPIC gpcdll.h gpcdll.c produces the same error message.

Update #5: I tried:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-Bstatic -L.\ -lgpclib.a -fPIC gpcdll.h gpcdll.c
```

Which is supposed to specify the current working directory as the search path but it still saying:

> gpcdll.c:19:17: fatal error: gpc.h: No such file or directory

Update #6: So I finally got frustrated enough and removed all the code from the static library (gpc.h & gpc.c) and put them in the same directory as the gpcdll.h gpcdll.c and was able to compile but I feel like you should be able to link a static library that contains that code and it must be something simple that I am missing.

Comment: Well I googled it and found the answer: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=682261. In your case `-gpclib.a ` should be `-lgpclib.a`  - `-g` relates to debug level and `pclib.a` is not a valid level argument.  Looks like a simple typographical error - voting to close.

Comment: @Clifford I attempted to run the following and receive a new error stating it cannot find my static library now: gcc -shared -Bstatic -lgpclib.a -fPIC gpcdll.h gpcdll.c which make sense because it does not start with an l.

Comment: The l in -lxxxx is not part of the file name, it is the command option. However it should be -lgpc.  The lib part is implicit - my error.

Comment: @Clifford gcc -shared -lgpc -gpclib.a -fPIC gpcdll.h gpcdll.c produces the same error message.

Comment: Well, that then is a different question.  You have fixed the question you asked about.  Not finding a library file is due to its path not being defined in a -L option.  SO is not the place to learn how to drive the toolchain - there's a manual for that.

Comment: @Clifford The static library is located in the same directory as the the .h and .c files. Does it still need to be specified? If I do need to specify the full path how to do I use -l to do that? I tried -l:/<full path>/ but it still did not work.

Comment: Why do you pass gpcdll.h on the command line?

Comment: RTFM! `-L` and `-l` (lowercase) are distinct options. `-L.\ -lgpc` specifies the current working directory as a library search path and gpclib.a as a library to link.

Comment: Do not change the question to a different question once it has answers.  Post a new question.  Update 4 still has the erroneous -gpclib.a option - why would you expect a different error message if you repeated the same error!  Try: `gcc -shared -L.\ -lgpc -fPIC gpcdll.c`.  If that does not work _and_ it generates a different result that your original question, post a new question (or better - read the manual)

Comment: Try something like `gcc -shared -fPIC gpcdll.c gpclib.a`. You might need a `-I` option to specify the location of the "gpc.h" file.

Answer (score 0):

The [`-g` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) takes, optionally, a debug level:

> Request debugging information and also use level to specify how much information. The default level is 2.

`gcc` is just parsing `pclib.a` as if it was a debug output level.

As for your Update #2 error, that is a compilation error (`gcc`'s preprocessor couldn't find the `gpc.h` header -- you need to make that file visible to `gcc`, either installing/moving the header or telling it to find headers in more places using the [`-I` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)), which is different than your original error (an error invoking `gcc`).

Comment: I attempted to run with -g and received no additional debugging information, only the same error message as before

Comment: @Josh: in this case, *debugging information* refers to information used by a debugger, rather than something to help you understand an error. In other words, the `-g` option tells `gcc` to emit extra information meant to by used by a debugger; it has nothing to do with debugging `gcc` itself or your invocation of `gcc`.